# How can I make page that admin only can access?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

I want to add one page that admin only can access in Shopify.
So the other clients can't see the link and can't access that site.
To do this, I should get user email I think. So that I can give permission to certain users.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this app for page lock functionality.

APP URL: https://apps.shopify.com/locksmith

REF Doc: https://docs.uselocksmith.com/